# preg_match gives only one match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to create a url handler and I tried to use preg_match for finding the variables. 
So here is the preg_match that I get after the variable replacing of the url format (ex:post/%id%/%title%) -

```
preg_match("/post\/[0-9]+\/[a-z-א-ת-]+/i","post/5/lol",$match);
```

My problem that $match returns only this inside array -

> "post/5/lol"

And not an array like that -

```
Array ( 
        [0] => "post/5/lol",
        [1] => "5",
        [2] => "lol"
      )
```

Can someone help me please to find out why it returns only one match?

Comment: You forgot to mark the capture groups with `()` signs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap each segment you wish to capture with parentheses, creating sub-expressions:

```
preg_match("/post\/([0-9]+)\/([a-z-א-ת-]+)/i", "post/5/lol", $match);
```

Comment: By the way, couldn't it be done with a simple `explode('/')` operation, I wonder?

Comment: @raina77ow:  Using `preg_match` allows you to restrict what input it allowed.  Walking an array made from `explode` is a pain, in this case.

Comment: I could but I want the user to select the url format.
And what will happen if i'l put the + sign outsite the round brackets?

Comment: @Yehonatan:  Only the first match will be returned, meaning the first character (`5` or `l`, in the example), which is undesired.

Comment: @Yehonatan:  No problem! Remember to mark this question as answered by clicking the green checkmark by my answer.

Comment: There was a 10 min time limit :)